# Kendo drop downlist is not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I want to add drop down list on top of my grid.But its not working right. what i need is to choose an item from the dropdown menu and populate the rest of the detail for the selected item on the grid 
but i am getting:

```
  **The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemIDFilter' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult _BinCard(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest, Int32)' in X.Controllers.ItemsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
    Parameter name: parameters**
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult _ItemDropdown([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
      {
          //
         var data = ReportEngineHelper.GetReportingEngine(Session).Generate<ItemDropDownQuery>().ToQueryModel<ItemDropDownModel>();
         return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }




  public ActionResult _BinCard([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int itemIDFilter)
            {
                var data = ReportEngineHelper.GetReportingEngine(Session).Generate<BinCardQuery>(new Filter()
                {
                   Item  = new Item(){ItemID = itemIDFilter}
                }).ToQueryModel<BinCard>();
                return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
```

view:

```
    @using HCMIS.Dashboard.Core.Models.Items
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Item : </td>

        <td>
            @( 
    Html.Kendo().DropDownList() 
        .Name("Itemdropdownlist") 
        .DataTextField("FullItemName") 
        .DataValueField("ItemID") 
        .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("_ItemDropdown", "Items"))) 
        .OptionLabel("Select an Item") ) 
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="/Content/Images/go.png" valign="top" onclick="loadGrid('BinCardGrd', false)" alt="Go" title="Go" style="width:20px;height:18px;margin-top:2px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid<BinCard>()
    .Name("BinCardGrd")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("_BinCard", "Items").Data("readItemIdFilter")))

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Item).Width(550);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Unit).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(c => c.dateFormat).Title("Date").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.InvoiceNo).Title("No.").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Received).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Issued).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.SupplierTo).Title("Supplier/To").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity).Title("Quantity").Width(200);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Balance).Title("Balance").Width(200);
        }
    )
  .Sortable()

      )




<script>function readItemIdFilter() {
    var IID = $("#Itemdropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
 return {
        itemIDFilter: (IID.dataValueField)
    };
} </script>
```

model:

```
   public class ItemDropDownModel
    {
        public int ItemID{ get; set; }
        public string FullItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemWithCommodityType { get; set; }

    }
```

BinCardQuery:

```
public override string Generate()
        {


     QueryString = string.Format(@"`

        Select FullItemName Item,`
         Unit, GRNFDate [Date], Supplier,  Null InvoiceNo, Received, Issued, 
           SUM(IsNull(Received,0) - IsNull(Issued, 0)) 
           OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber asc) As Balance
            From Transactions.StockOnHandBase 
           where EnvironmentID = {0} and  itemid = {1}
     ", EnvironmentID, Item.ItemID);
                return QueryString;
            }

        public Item Item { get; set; }
```

Comment: check your url Items/_ItemDropdown for the data on your browser. And you can also use F12 (developer tools) and watch the Network tab. Try to avoid JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in your final release.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
@( 
Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Itemdropdownlist")
    .DataTextField("FullItemName")
    .DataValueField("ItemID")
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("_ItemDropdown", "Home")))
    .OptionLabel("Select an Item"))
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public JsonResult _ItemDropdown()
{
    List<ItemDropDownModel> lst = new List<ItemDropDownModel>();

    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 1, FullItemName = "1", ItemWithCommodityType = "1" });
    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 11, FullItemName = "11", ItemWithCommodityType = "11" });
    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 111, FullItemName = "111", ItemWithCommodityType = "111" });

    return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In-addition I have also updated your controller code.

```
    public JsonResult _ItemDropdown()
    {
        var data = ReportEngineHelper.GetReportingEngine(Session).Generate<ItemDropDownQuery>().ToQueryModel<ItemDropDownModel>();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Let me know if any concern.

**Update 1:**

**VIEW**

```
@( 
 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("Itemdropdownlist")
        .DataTextField("FullItemName")
        .DataValueField("ItemID")
        .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("_ItemDropdown", "Home")))
        .OptionLabel("Select an Item")
        .Events(e =>
            {
                e.Change("onChanges");
            })
        )
<br />
@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.BinCard>()
    .Name("BinCardGrd")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("_BinCard", "Home").Data("readItemIdFilter")))

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Item).Width(550);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Unit).Width(100);
        }
    )
  .Sortable()

      )

<script>
    function readItemIdFilter() {

        var IID = $("#Itemdropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");

        var ddvalue = 0;
        debugger;
        if (IID.dataItem() && IID.dataItem().ItemID) {
            ddvalue = IID.dataItem().ItemID;
        }
        return {
            itemIDFilter: ddvalue
        };
    }

    function onChanges(e) {
        $('#BinCardGrd').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        $('#BinCardGrd').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    }

</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public JsonResult _ItemDropdown()
{
    List<ItemDropDownModel> lst = new List<ItemDropDownModel>();

    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 1, FullItemName = "1", ItemWithCommodityType = "1" });
    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 11, FullItemName = "11", ItemWithCommodityType = "11" });
    lst.Add(new ItemDropDownModel() { ItemID = 111, FullItemName = "111", ItemWithCommodityType = "111" });

    return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult _BinCard([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int itemIDFilter)
{
    List<BinCard> lst = new List<BinCard>();
    lst.Add(new BinCard() { Item = "2", Unit = itemIDFilter.ToString() });
    lst.Add(new BinCard() { Item = "22", Unit = itemIDFilter.ToString() });
    lst.Add(new BinCard() { Item = "222", Unit = itemIDFilter.ToString() });

    return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but what i need is to pass the itemid from the dropdownlist to a controller that will view in the grid

Comment: On dropdown selection change event you want to bind grid, right?

Comment: yes please. i cant seem to bind the dropdown with the grid